# Filter index values in koalas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spark-koalas

I am trying to recreate the below operation in kolas, In pandas this works when i try the same in koalas it throws an error.

**Operation tried in Pandas:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'bar':['1', '2', '3','4','5']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':['1', '2', '3']})

ci = [4,32,12,1]

df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(ci)]
```

**Output:**

foo  bar
1   b   2
4   e   5

**Operation tried in Koalas:**

```
df = ks.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'bar':['1', '2', '3','4','5']})
df1 = ks.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':['1', '2', '3']})

ci = [4,32,12,1]

df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(ci)]
```

**Output:**
PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Index.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Index.get_level_values()` is using `__iter__()` behind the scenes, which is not supported in Koalas.

Couple of thoughts:

1. Why the need to use `get_level_values()` at all?
   `df[df.index.isin(ci)]` works just as well.
2. The "proper" way to index with missing labels would be to use `.reindex()`. It would fill the rows that are missing from the new index with NaNs, which you'll have to drop:

```py
new_df = df.reindex(index=ci).dropna()
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Accept the answer if it answered your question.